# Amazon Quicksight Dynamic date filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

so everyday  I receive sales data from the previous day. So today November 15 I have data from July 2021 until November 14 2021. What I want is to show this data for the current month by aggregating by day. I use a quicksight visual with a MTD (Month To Date) filter. Everything is fine so far.
The problem is on each first date of the month, I see "No Data" on my visual which is normal since I do not have any data from the current day/month but as I said earlier from the day before.

So what I want to achieve is:

- Each 1st of current month: show data from the whole previous month
- From 2nd to last day of current month: show data from the current month

Can someone help me please to know how I can achieve this?

I looked for ways to do this and I found dynamic default parameters but this option is not fine with me since I have to fill a username column according to the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-set-up.html) and I have many users so it will be not interesting to list all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign parameters to a group rather than a specific user which is much quicker

Answer (score 0):

There is new functionality which allows you to set today or beginning/ending of month/quater/year as default.

See screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO2OB.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).